# Wordpress wrong dates bug

Tags: php, date, date-time

I am using Wordpress version 5.4.

I have a problem with the dates in a CPT, and it is that the dates show one day less.

Example: If I put in the backend the date, 08/18/20, in the frontend it shows me 08/17/20

I think for some reason the date_i18n function is not executing correctly.

This is the code where I show the dates:

```
<time><?php if (isset($event_from_date) && $event_from_date <> '') echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), strtotime($event_from_date)) . ','; ?></time>
```

Comment: And you're sure you have the right time zone set in WP?

Comment: Yes, is configured correctly. In fact I get this error all of a sudden. @vancoder

Comment: Try dissabling cache. I have seen the same problem before